# Using an integral controller, How to ensure that a state feedback control system could exactly track a specific frequency references?

Tags: control-theory

For a typical state space model, i.e.

$$
\dot{x} = Ax + Bu 
$$
$$
y = Cx 
$$

how can you augment the system such that a feedback control system could track a specific frequency reference (say, 400Hz) while completely rejecting constant disturbances?

By Integral Controller I mean something like:

[Integral Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAKFj.png)

where

$
A_{a} = \begin{matrix} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & w_{r} & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & -w_{r} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & w_{t} \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & -w_{t} & 0 \\ 
\end{matrix} 
$

and

$
B_{a} = \begin{matrix} 
1\\ 
0 \\ 
1\\ 
0 \\ 
1 \\ 
\end{matrix} 
$

where $w_{r}$ is the frequency being rejected and $w_{t}$ is the frequency being tracked. **If there is no frequency being rejected, What should the $A_{a}$ and $B_{a}$ matrix look like?** Should I use a 3x3 matrix with the $w_{r}$ removed or do I just set $w_{r}$ to zero? i.e.

$
A_{a} = \begin{matrix} 
0 & 0 & 0  \\ 
0 & 0 & w_{t} \\ 
0 & -w_{t} & 0 \\ 
\end{matrix} 
$

and

$
B_{a} = \begin{matrix} 
1\\ 
0 \\ 
1 \\ 
\end{matrix} 
$

**OR**

$
A_{a} = \begin{matrix} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & w_{t} \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & -w_{t} & 0 \\ 
\end{matrix} 
$

and

$
B_{a} = \begin{matrix} 
1\\ 
0 \\ 
1\\ 
0 \\ 
1 \\ 
\end{matrix} 
$

thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to augment a state space model to ensure that a state feedback control system could exactly track a specific frequency references?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3192400/how-to-augment-a-state-space-model-to-ensure-that-a-state-feedback-control-syste)

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear at the moment. You say you want to reject constant disturbances, but at the same time you write "where $\omega_r$ is the frequency being rejected". Which disturbances do you mean now, constant or sine? It is also unclear which part of the matrices are part of the plant and which of the controller: Usually, the term "augmented system" (matrix) refers to the closed loop system (matrix), including both plant and controller. Your definition seems to include only the controller. Can you also provide the plant $(A,B,C)$ matrices in addition to $(A_a,B_a)$?